# PhpStorm refactor local variable to class field

Tags: php, ide, refactoring, phpstorm

Like in topic, i want to refactor local variable to class field.

I was thinking of two approaches:

A. Quick and simple:
I want to refactor name of variable from `$var` to `$this->var`.

B. Extended version:

from:

```
class x {
    function y() {
        $var = new targetClass;
    }
}
```

to:

```
class x {
    /** @var targetClass $var */ // version C, optional
    (public|protected|private) $var;
    function y() {
        $this->var = new targetClass;
    }
}
```

Can't do any of this, when I try to refactor `$var`, simply by refactoring it to `$this->var`, I end up with a message:

> Inserted identifier is invalid

Defining `$this->var` first doesn't help either.

Only workaround I found is to type `$this->var`, loose focus on refactoring variable, type whatever and delete it. Then PhpStorm is cheated and variable is changed. It simple dirty-covers approach A.

Comment: That "Refactor | Rename" can only change the name of the variable.. but not the nature of it .. which is what you are trying to do (changing local var to class field). You just have to use different Refactoring tool as already suggested by Björn Fyrvall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the variable and rightclick. Choose Refactor->Extract->Field. Enter the name you wan't for the field.